# How to get the width of an ionic component in Ionic 4? eg: ion-grid

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ion-grid

I want to create a perfect square with width=height.
Width depends on the the view width of the page.
I'm using ion-grid as the root of my custom component.
How to get the height of ion-grid?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Nothing I wrote worked. I don't have anything for the moment. But I can tell you that I used ion-grid, ion-row, ion-col most of the time. If nothing works until Monday I will obliged to use <div> from html, which I tried to avoid at all cost because I'm developing a cross-platform application for IOS, Android and web. I Don't know what will be the cost of using <div> in an ionic application, @E.Maggini, if you know why I should avoid <div>, it'd be amazing if you share it with me.

Comment: use `width: 20vw; height: 20vw;` in component css.. change the number as per your requirement. this will change the size of the component as per the device width..

Comment: I thought about doing this on a parent to the component and set paddings as a last resort if nothing works. But there should be something way to get the length of an ionic component. @ChetanBansal I'm sure your method totally works.

Comment: you can try referencing the ion-grid with @ViewComponent and then read the dimensions of the component.. assign those back with ngStyle to the component you want to change the dimensions.. something like this https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-get-element-height-and-width-in-angularexample.html

Comment: I tried it before, this technique is used for Angular, but for some reason, in Ionic, it returns undefined. I tried also another technique it returned 0. I keep searching for a simple solution. Anyway, thanks @ChetanBansal for your suggestions.

Comment: Could you please create a Stackblitz demo with your code? You can use [this starter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-starter-app?file=src/app/app.component.ts) if you want :)